# How can a beginner develop an automated testing framework completely from scratch?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, appium, protractor

I am completely into manual testing, I was asked by my manager to start developing an automated framework for my company website and mobile application. I am a complete beginner and have a very little programming knowledge.

When I inquired with my other friends from testing, they have told it is impossible for a beginner to develop a framework from scratch. I wanted to know is it really that hard? Or can I do it with proper learning?

It would be very helpful if you can let me know, what is the best way to start?

My company uses angular for websites. Hence, after some research, I came to a conclusion that Protractor is the best automation framework for angular websites. I have also read few third-party tools like TestingWhiz with no coding, which can also be used for mobile testing.

What do I need to know to do as my manager wants?

Comment: Vote to close this question as opinion-based. Some developers can some cant. Each might consider different ways as the best ways to start.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus more on how a beginner can build test automation from scratch rather than whether they can do it. If this isn't what you want, you can always revert my edits.

Comment: It would be prudent for all parties to define the expectations for the project. I can imagine a scenario where the manager has unrealistic expectations for the return on investment of time and resources. The reality is that it will probably take a beginner quite some time to produce an automated test framework that provides any real value to the company.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible with proper learning and practice. Start to automate with a simple test case.

Don't lose your hope when your first test gets failed keep on trying.

For Automating the AngularJS Application **Protractor** is the good Choice

You need to learn basics of JavaScript before starting to write the code. I have listed few links for you to go through the basics of Protractor tools.

- [Protractor Testing](https://www.guru99.com/protractor-testing.html)
- [Protractor for End to End Testing](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/protractor-testing-tutorial/)
- [Protractor](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/protractor-angularjs-tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A beginner can also start developing automation framework with proper guidance from the seniors.

For Automating a application beginners needs to consider the following things:

- Select a automation tool that provide easy and better solution for the application.
- Select what are the test cases that you are going to automate. All the test cases can't be automated.
- Break the test cases into small modules.
- Verify the tool is a open source or paid tool
- Verify the tool you are choosing is best for automating the current application and also to your company

To answer to your question :

Yes, protractor seems to be a better choice in automation the angular application. But you needs to be good in Javascript and selenium.

To automate the mobile application you need to consider the following things

- Price of the automation tool.
- How long you can access the tool free.
- How many test cases you can automate for free.
- The tool is scale-able and it should support both android and IOS platforms for automation
- Verify the tool support continuous integration.
- Supports end-to-end testing.

For Mobile automation there are many tools available

- [Katalon studio](https://www.katalon.com/)
- [Endtest IO](https://endtest.io/)
- [Seetest continuous integration](https://experitest.com/)
- [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/)
- [Calabash](https://calaba.sh/)

Each tools has his own advantage in terms of price, number of test cases provided for free, continuous integration and End to End testing. Select the better one.

Answer (score 1):

**Test automation should be a team effort; you know testing and your developer coworkers know coding. Both should work together on it and share the responsibility. This is the most important feedback you should give to your manager.**

A test framework is a software application. A software application should be build by somewhat experienced programmers to avoid getting one big mess of spaghetti code. You as a tester are a key stakeholder in the process of building this application.

I would encourage you to find some developers that have some interest in new technologies, improving processes and quality. Ask them if they want to participate straight from the start. If you bypass them now and ask for their help later, they will be less inclined to dive into it (or possibly fix the mess you've created by yourself).
As this will continuously cost time from developers, you need support from your manager.

Once you have some developers involved, THEN start looking together into tool selection, code architecture, build server integration, strategy to build up regression test coverage, adding acceptance test driven development to the team workflow etc.
You should then gradually be able to first start with writing test specifications (i.e. in Gherkin), then implement the code for the tests and then later perhaps also changes to the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prasanna mentioned, Katalon Studio is very user friendly and it is not for mobile testing only. There's also web testing, API testing, DB functionalities.

You can record test via a GUI and later if you are comfortable with coding skills you can switch to script mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about being possible or not, but about the quality of the end product- test software in your case.

Could you build your company's product from scratch ? you probably could, but it wouldn't be very good or successful.

"Automated testing framework" is a project like any other project, you can quickly hack something as proof of concept but if you want it to be useful you need to plan and architect it properly, and this requires experience.

When you choose a tool you need to consider the common -ilities (extend-ability, usability, maintainability, etc.), limitations and benefits of the tool (no-programming tools are usually limited in applying test logic), needed resources for your future needs (budget and personnel) and other things as well.

What to do then ? it's hard to say, if you are talented, willing to learn and most importantly have supporting managers you can take a risk and take the project. Otherwise ask for help, it will be for your own good in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I read your questions carefully and understand the possibilities or scenarios in which your manager might have asked (No offence intended). There are many managers, when they say start building the framework, they really not meant by framework, they sometime thought testing code may be a framework, so you have to have discussion in detail with him and try to understand what he means. Does he mean framework means a common framework to be used across many mobile applications or just a sole framework for current application, that is important.

For a fresher it's not impossible, but it takes time to optimize it, and it comes with experience of different framework use as well as build experience.